# error "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'createComponent' of undefined" when work with dynamic component in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to add the components dynamically in angular4.
I checked with other questions, But i cant find solution.
I got the error

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'createComponent' of undefined

on dynamic components.

**adv.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterContentInit, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, ComponentFactoryResolver } from '@angular/core';
import { SampleComponent } from '../sample/sample.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-adv',
  templateUrl: './adv.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./adv.component.css']
})
export class AdvComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit {
  @ViewChild('container', {read:'ViewContainerRef'}) container;
  constructor(private resolver : ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterContentInit(){
    const sampleFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(SampleComponent);
    this.container.createComponent(sampleFactory);
  }

}
```

**adv.component.html**

```
<div #container></div>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AdvComponent } from './adv/adv.component';
import { SampleComponent } from './sample/sample.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AdvComponent,
    SampleComponent
  ],
  entryComponents:[
    SampleComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

About `ngAfterViewInit` in [docs](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence):

> Respond after Angular initializes the component's views and child
>   views.

while `ngAfterContentInit`:

> Respond after Angular projects external content into the component's
>   view.

So the child view is not ready in `ngAfterContentInit`, so move this part

```
ngAfterContentInit(){
    const sampleFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(SampleComponent);
    this.container.createComponent(sampleFactory);
  }
```

to

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    const sampleFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(SampleComponent);
    this.container.createComponent(sampleFactory);
}
```

Also change:

```
  @ViewChild('container', {read:'ViewContainerRef'}) container;
```

to

```
@ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef }) container: ViewContainerRef
```

Comment: try changing for this: @ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef }) container: ViewContainerRef

Comment: If you don't define the type, it will be HTMLElement and it doesn't have node properties, but ViewContainerRef has